# Missing required parameter for [Route: admin.request.update] [URI: admin/request/{request}] [Missing parameter: request]

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I got an error when I tried to access detail.blade.php that said "Missing required parameter for [Route: admin.request.update] [URI: admin/request/{request}] [Missing parameter: request].". I don't know where did I do wrong, because I copied the steps and codes exactly like my other project that did the same thing (editing data).

Here is my detail.blade.php :

```
 <form action="{{ route('admin.request.update', $requestStock) }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="name" name="name" rows="3" readonly value="{{ $requestStock->name }}"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="status" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Complete</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select class=" form-control" name="status" id="status">
                            <option name="status" value="1" {{ $requestStock->status == '1' ? 'selected' : ''}}> Not Completed </option>
                            <option name="status" value="0" {{ $requestStock->status == '0' ? 'selected' : ''}}> Complete </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 100%">Update</button>
            </form>
```

And this is my RequestPageController :

```
public function edit(RequestStock $requestStock)
{
    return view('admin.request.detail')->with([
        'requestStock' => $requestStock,
    ]);
}

public function update(Request $request, RequestStock $requestStock)
{
    $requestStock->status = $request->status;
    $requestStock->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.request.index');
}
```

Route :

```
 Route::namespace("App\Http\Controllers\Admin")->prefix("admin")->name("admin.")->middleware('can:adminpage')->group(function () {
     Route::resource("/request", RequestPageController::class);
 });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your route too. For a start, try `{{ route('admin.request.update', ['request' => $requestStock]) }}`

Comment: @brombeer I've updated my question, and I also tried your suggestion but still get the same error

Comment: use php artisan optimize:clear to clear route cache and than try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try the following changes:

Changed Route:

```
Route::namespace("App\Http\Controllers\Admin")->prefix("admin")->name("admin.")->middleware('can:adminpage')->group(function () {
     Route::resource("/request-stock", RequestPageController::class);
 });
```

Changed RequestPageController:

```
public function edit(RequestStock $requestStock)
{
    return view('admin.request-stock.detail')->with([
        'requestStock' => $requestStock,
    ]);
}

public function update(Request $request, RequestStock $requestStock)
{
    $requestStock->status = $request->status;
    $requestStock->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.request-stock.index');
}
```